# Is it possible to integrate akeneo with my non cms PHP website?

Tags: php, akeneo

I am trying to learn what [Akeneo](https://www.akeneo.com/) can do.

I understand it's a Product Information Management (PIM) and I can integrate it with several CMS like Wordpress, Shopify, and Magento.

However, I'd like to ask if anyone knows whether or not I can integrate Akeneo with my own PHP website so the user can create a product in Akeneo and my eCommerce application automatically fetch it from the Akeneo platform and display it to the client.

Comment: They provide an API (https://api.akeneo.com/), so the answer is yes.

Comment: Since you answered first, do you want to add a "Stack overflow" answer (instead of comment) to this question so I can accept as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can, but you need to make a custom module that connects your custom CMS with Akeneo.

I recommend you to check how are made those connectors.